# My Python code is not working like I think it should

Tags: python

I am getting my feet wet in Python, and I have been staring at this code for the past hour or two. Even though I know that my program has generated the correct sequence of numbers, the so called Pythagorean triple, the logic will not "grab" the triple. This is Euler problem #9.

```
#https://projecteuler.net/problem=9
def main(num):
    i = num
    j = k = 0
    while i >= 0:
        while j >= k:
            print(i, ",", j, ",", k, ": ", i*i, "=", j*j + k*k) 
            if i*i == j*j + k*k & i > j > k: # this line here should detect the triple
                print("found")
                print(i, ",", j, ",", k)
                break
            j -= 1
            k += 1
        i -= 1
        j = 1000 - i
        k = 0


main(1000)
#The Pythagorean triple is 425, 375, 200, and the sum is 1000
#The product is 31875000
```

This line here apparently...

```
if i*i == j*j + k*k & i > j > k: #this line here should detect the triple
```

...does not return true, even if the program correctly generates the triplet (425,375,200)

I'm sure I must have missed something totally obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably want to use the logical and operator `and` (the Python equivalent of C and Java's `&&`) instead of the bitwise and operator `&`.

It might also help to add some brackets to make sure the operators are being evaluated with the precedence that you want.

The following line works for me:

```
if (i*i == j*j + k*k) and (i > j > k): # should detect the triple
```

Comment: This suggestion didn't work for me. I tried to break down the entire boolean statement into a set of if statements and this strategy didn't work either.

Comment: You also need some brackets. I've updated my answer.

Comment: This odd, it's still not working for me. If it's working for you, then I must be doing something wrong.

Comment: I think you'll find that it is printing out "found", but because your `break` is only breaking out of the inner loop, it continues to run. If you remove your debug print statement then it should work as expected.

Comment: Thanks, I just substituted break with a return statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the line with comment with the following code.
Understand one thing- In python "and" is there instead of "&&" in C.

if ( (i ** 2 )==((j ** 2)+(k ** 2)) ) and (i > j > k):

If your code is logically correct,Then this should work.